# Characterization of connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

The following fact can be found in "Characterization of connected real functions" by B. D. Garrett , 1971.

**Fact**. Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function. Then  graph of $f$ is connected iff whenever $D$ is continuum in $\Bbb R^2$ which contains points above and below the graph of $f,$ then $D$ meets the graph of $f.$ (Continuum is compact and connected)

**Corollary**. Let $f\colon (a,b)\to\Bbb R$ be a function with disconnected graph. Let $F\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be any extension of the function $f.$ Then $F$ has a disconnected graph.

Comment: In the Fact, where is $f$ defined? On all of $\mathbb R$? What is the precise meaning of above and below? You should  edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: @PaulFrost, I edited. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it is okay now.

Comment: @PaulFrost, you meant the proof is correct right ?

Comment: I meant that my two questions have been clarified. But after I read your question once more, I think that there is still one more essential point. Make clear that you want to *prove* something about functions $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ and that the part beginning  with " Let $F$ be any extension of $f$" is the proof. As it is stands, I find it confusing.

Comment: And I suggest that you give an official *answer* to your own question. Delete the proof  from your question and write it as the answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Is it clear now?

Comment: Not really. When I read "Let $f\colon (a,b)\to\Bbb R$ be a function with disconnected graph. By using the above fact there exists a continuum $D$ in $(a,b)\times \Bbb R$ that contains points above and below $\text{Graf}(f)$", then I think that this should be a reformulation  of the Fact. But it is not. So write "Corollary: Let $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ ..." and then "Proof: ....".

Comment: @PaulFrost, I am doing it now

Comment: @PaulFrost, I did what you recommended  to me . Please if you find my question is important . kindly, asking for vote for the question and the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Paul Frost for checking my answer.

Here it is

**Proof**. Let's denote the graph of $f$ by $\text{Graf} (f).$ By using the above fact there exists a continuum $D$ in $(a,b)\times \Bbb R$ that contains points above and below $\text{Graf}(f)$, that is, there exist points $(c,z_1),(d,z_2)\in D$ such that $z_1>f(c)$ and $z_2<f(d),$  such that $\text{Graf} \ (f) \cap D=\emptyset.$ Notice that $D$ is still continuum in $\Bbb R^2$ and has points above and below the graph of $F.$ So, by the fact above, $F$ has a disconnected graph.

The following it is easy to see

**Corollary**. Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function with connected graph. Then $f\restriction I$ has a connected graph for any non-empty interval $I.$

Comment: It is essentially okay, but your proof has a gap: You apply the Fact to a function living on $(a,b)$, not on $\mathbb R$. There are certainly many ways to fill this gap, but I think the following is a good approach: Take a homeomorphism $h : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$. Then apply the Fact to $g = f \circ h^{-1}$. Note that 1. $(h \times id_{\mathbb R})(Graph(f)) = Graph(g)$ 2. $Graph(f)$ is connected iff $Graph(g)$ is connected 3. $D \subset (a,b) \times \mathbb R$ is a continuum iff $(h \times id_{\mathbb R})(D)$ is a continuum.

Comment: Paul Frost, Thank you so much , but one more question why we can not apply the fact to f direct is it because the the fact was essential for $\Bbb R$

Comment: Yes, the Fact deals only with functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. You have a function $f$ living on a genuine subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Thank you very much.